# Orientation Change Closed my floating Context Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In my app, I have a `ListView` with `List` item, long press will display `ContextMenu`. Here, I need to do `Orientation` change. So that, I followed like without adding `onConfigChanges` attribute in Manifest file manually i have handle that `Orientation` change using `onRetainNonConfigurationChanges()` method.

My issue is after item long press it will show the `ContextMenu` on that time if change the Orientation it's getting closed.

Please refer any solution other than adding `android:onConfigChnage="orienation"` in Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue is occurring due to the restarting of `Activity`. When the screen `Orientation` changes, android system restart the current `Activity`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222525/android-activity-restartdue-to-screen-orientation-changes-issue-solutions-prov) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android) the same issue. May be you get some idea.

Comment: Yes you are right dude. i know about this already but only problem is i have retained all the values and i have used two different layout for that same activity but i can't able to avoid the floating Context menu closing.

Answer (score -1):

that is the normal behaviour.
ContextMenus just like alert dialogs are part of the activity life cycle and as such, they get killed with the activity.

the solution is override `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and save the current state of your activity and get the savedInstanceState back during your activity `onCreate`

Comment: Hmm yea...I know here i am using another method like onRetainNonConigurationChanges() method to retain the values.But my issue is That floating Context Menu is closing on the Orientation Changing time.Here what i need to do is i need to keep show the Context Menu even though orientation changing time.For that as you said like dialog means i need to check the Context Menu is showing or not and then i need to show it again explicitly in onResume() method after activity created.For these thing i need your guide lines.

Comment: you just explain the solution yourself. I won't write the code for you. Whenever you're opening the menu, you set a flag, whenever closing you reset the flag. You pass this flag over during orientation changes and onResume you check its value to open again or not the menu.

Comment: Dude...Here you can't check whether the context menu is opened or not?

Comment: but you can override the `onContextItemSelected` and `onContextMenuClosed` and set/reset some boolean or integer to know that it is opened.